By 5e RAW, is there any way short of Wish, to become a playable sandwich?
Inspired by the old 3e/3.5e "psionic sandwich", I was trying to determine whether such a character could be created by 5e rules.
A few base criteria seem important:
• Tasty. (If you can't eat it, is it really a sandwich?)
• Permanent until dispelled, or at least possible to maintain during all waking hours.
• The sandwich will need INT\WIS\CHA scores for purposes of communication.
Movement, Mage Hand, & Telepathy or other language, would each be beneficial, but not strictly necessary for the purposes of this question.
Characters in older editions, would Polymorph a sandwich to the form of a creature, hijack its body & end the polymorph (retaining their stats by some transitive property?), but 5e's 4th Lvl Polymorph spell only affects creatures to begin with.
True Polymorph can turn an object into a creature or a creature into an object, but the mental stats are lost & the creature remembers nothing of its time as an object... A sandwich True Polymorphed to a creature then allowed to turn back into a sandwich, seems to lose its mental stats unless some other property retains it.
It seems that the Magic Jar spell would lose its target & be suppressed when its target humanoid is in object form; so, that doesn't seem to help us keep those tasty mental stats in sandwich form either...
I thought there was some subclass that allowed Wild Shaping into a monstrosity (Juvenile Mimic), but perhaps that was unofficial...
I find precious few ways to become Tiny all day, much less to appear as a Tiny object all day...
I'd prefer a Small sandwich that doesn't target as a creature, over any size creature with only the illusion of a sandwich, but it actually seems pretty tricky to even look like a sandwich all day, to a crowd of people...
And really, if people can't get a bready layered bite of this player character sandwich, I don't feel it's really fulfilled the goal...
Is there any way besides Wish, to play as a delicious sandwich all day?

I can see several Magic Jar & Polymorph related questions, relevant to this, but I'm not sure which to link. Open to suggestions

@Thomas_Markov I wasn't aware of the [food-and-drink] tag Thanks! I had the [character-advancement] tag because this didn't seem like something one could do at Lvl 1.

Magic Jar
There are no features that animate objects without causing them to become creatures, so even if you could transform into or possess a sandwich, you would still be a creature. If that suits your needs, check out How dangerous can I make my tankard? for ways to enhance animated objects.
If you simply want to exist as a sandwich without combat capabilities, you could use the first part of magic jar with a bit of DM buy-in. The material component for magic jar is:

a gem, crystal, reliquary, or some other ornamental container worth at least 500 gp

If you could convince your DM that a particularly expensive sandwich operates as an ornamental container, you could then store your soul in said container:

Your body falls into a catatonic state as your soul leaves it and enters the container you used for the spell's material component. While your soul inhabits the container, you are aware of your surroundings as if you were in the container's space.

Telepathy
It isn't clear, so you should ask your DM, but you may be able to communicate from the jar using non-action-based telepathy, some sources of which include:

Warlock (The Great Old One) feature: Awakened Mind
Feat: Telepathic

While these are one-way telepathy options, you are aware of your surroundings while in a magic jar, so you can hear your respondents without difficulty.
Movement
If telepathy is allowed, the best bet for movement is a familiar:

While your familiar is within 100 feet of you, you can communicate with it telepathically.

Getting the warlock feature Pact of the Chain will also allow a more useful familiar with hands so you could be carried more easily.
Being Eaten
All this said, I'd be wary about being eaten. A bite or two might be fine, but:

If the container is destroyed or the spell ends, your soul immediately returns to your body. If your body is more than 100 feet away from you or if your body is dead when you attempt to return to it, you die.

...so either keep your original body nearby, or make sure your sandwich isn't eaten to the point where it falls apart as sandwiches are want to do.

A sandwich contains its fillings, so it's a container. And chives are considered an ornamental plant...

This answer subverts the expected use of Magic Jar, to intentionally remain within the container; which is exactly the sort of status I was looking for! It's dangerous & fragile & therefore from a DM perspective I find it ideal. Frankly, I feel embarrassed that I didn't consider the possibility of considering (for example) a gilded sandwich of rare ingredients, to be a container worth at least 500gp. It seems arguable, so I'm interested to hear any counter-argument or other methods, before marking this as Accepted, but I think this answer could work, by RAW?
